# Pass Datetime to http post request c#

Tags: c#, datetime, postman

I am trying to post request object which contains datetime via postman:

```
{
   "calcDate":   "2016-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-00:00",
   "userIds": [
        0
   ],
  "fileOutputType": "csv"
}
```

my object and controller method look like this:

```js
public class UserRequest {
  public DateTime CalcDate {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public int[] UserIds {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public FileOutputType FileOutputType {
    get;
    set;
  }
}


[HttpPost("getResults")]
public async Task < IActionResult > GetResults([FromBody] UserRequest request) {
  var result = await _srvc.GetResults(request);
  var fileName = "intelektas_calc" + DateTime.Now + "." + request.FileOutputType;
  return File(result, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
}
```

How to correctly pass Datetime object? I get `Null` in my request if I pas i like: `"2016-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-00:00"` but it works if I pass timestamp. However I need to pass date not timestamp. How to fix that?

this is swagger request example:

```
{
   "calcDate": "2020-05-18T11:39:46.063Z",
   "userIds": [
    0
   ],
  "fileOutputType": "csv"
}
```

but it also doesn't work. Is it possible at all? No format seems to work for me except timestamp. But user who will use the API probably doesn't even know what timestamp is, that's why I want DateTime instead.

my json options:

```js
mvc.AddJsonOptions(
                opt =>
                {
                    opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                    opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true });
                    opt.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new UnixDateTimeConverter());
                    opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    opt.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                    
                });
```

Comment: Try `2016-01-01T00:00:00.000` it works with my api

Comment: what json serialize settings you use in startup.cs? doesn't work for me

Comment: i don't set anything, i'll use the asp.net core default seriallizer. you can create a simple api and return a `DateTime` and see how your api serialize `DateTime` with postman and use that format to send data.

Comment: are values of userIds and fileOutputType Null as well or it's just the calcDate that is null?

Comment: also try `2016-01-01T10:00:00.000` idk if it's force time to be 24h or 12h

Comment: all values are null if I pas calcDate, if I only pass userIds and fileOutputType it works fine

Comment: Why are you using `UnixDateTimeConverter` if you're passing ISO8601 strings?  Remove that, and it should just work.